# Edge slides are behaving differently. Why?

Tags: modeling

I sometimes encounter an odd behavior, when I use edge slide. Can anyone tell me why this odd behavior happens?

I think the first GIF (below) is a normal behavior of edge slide. Both sides of adjacent vertices follow.

But I sometimes encounter something like the 2nd GIF behavior. In this case, the upper vertex does not follow the edge slide. Sometimes, both adjacent vertices do not follow. I even cannot see in which case this kind of things happen...

The object is made from an octagon. Using "extrude" and "scale", then I get this object. So I think all the vertices are connected properly. Or, I accidentally made some changes to vertices without realizing it???

- 1st: (I think this is normal)

[image]

- 2nd: One of the adjacent vertices does not follow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe because the you have non joint vertices for the "upper vertex" or doubled vertices

Comment: @lemon How does that thing happen? How vertices are unjointed ??

Comment: I think doubled. For instance, you extrude (but dont move, so this is 'invisible') and extrude again. If not, can you upload the file?

Comment: @lemon Thank you! You are right. It seems that I accidentally hitted "E" twice.

Comment: You have duplicated unconnected vertices. You can choose to select the duplicated vertices and merge them (Alt+M) or you can do "Remove Doubles.